# Attempting to understand functions in Python

Tags: python

This is an example of a coupled PDE that was solved using finite differences. Can someone tell me how arrh_expr was calculated if the range of temperature in its equation was never defined? I am trying to recreate this solution using a different method, but to do that I need to fully understand this first

```
import numpy as np

nz = 50
dz = 1 / nz
nt = 50
t = np.linspace(0, 4, nt)

p = np.array([0.01, 0.5, 1.0])

#Initialize concentration and temperature arrays
C = np.zeros(nz)
T = np.zeros(nz)

#Set initial condition for concentration
C[0] = 1.0

#Initialize arrays to store results
c_results = np.zeros((nt, nz))
T_results = np.zeros((nt, nz))

#Define the Arrhenius rate constant function
def k(temperature):
    arrh_expr = 4.68 * np.exp(-806 / ((600 - 273) * temperature + 273))
    return arrh_expr

#Calculate time derivative at specific spatial points
def rhsC(c0, c1, c2, T1, dz, p):
    return (p[0] * (c2 - 2 * c1 + c0) / dz**2 - 
            p[1] * (c2 - c0) / (2 * dz) - 
            p[2] * k(T1) * c1**2)

def rhsT(T0, T1, T2, c1, dz, p):
    return (0.01 * (T2 - 2 * T1 + T0) / dz**2 - 
            0.5 * (T2 - T0) / (2 * dz) + 
            2.45 * k(T1) * c1**2)

#Time-stepping loop
for it in range(nt):
    c_results[it, :] = C
    T_results[it, :] = T
    
    for iz in range(1, nz - 1):
        # Calculate concentration and temperature derivatives
        dc_dt = rhsC(C[iz - 1], C[iz], C[iz + 1], T[iz], dz, p)
        dT_dt = rhsT(T[iz - 1], T[iz], T[iz + 1], C[iz], dz, p)
        
        # Update concentration and temperature using forward Euler
        C[iz] += dz * dc_dt
        T[iz] += dz * dT_dt
```

Comment: `T1` is being passed as the `temperature` argument in expressions like `k(T1)`. Calling `k(blah)` passes in the value of `blah` as the value of `temperature` for example. This is how functions work in pure math and any other programming language ever. I recommend maybe starting at some basic tutorials if you've gone this far without that being clear.

Comment: Don't you see `k(T1)` in `rhsC()` and `rhsT()`?

Comment: It looks like `temperature` is just a scalar value being passed in to `k` as an argument. Following the call chain, I see `T1` being used as `temperature` where `k` is called in `rshC`, and that value (`T1`) is passed in from `T[iz]` in the inner `for` loop at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is a block of code meant to be reused, but to be able to reuse them in more than on case, we allow variables to be passed to them in the form of parameters. Consider the case where you want to create a function that perform the summation of two values, you can define it as

```
def sum():
    return 4+5
```

now this function is pretty useless in any case other than summing 4 and 5, so instead it makes since to allow it to sum any two variables, to do this we define a function that takes parameters e.g.

```
def sum(x, y):
    return x+y
```

this new function can now be called in the rest of our code by passing any two values as x and y and it will sum them up e.g.

```
sum(4, 5)
# returns 9
```

same thing applies here to you code, the function `k(temperature)` takes a value for temperature and based on it, it calculates the return value